# How to use global variables with Ray

Tags: python, parallel-processing, global-variables, ray

I have a script that looks like a more complicated version of this:

```
import ray 

var1 = 0
var2 = 0

@ray.remote
def create(n): 
    global var1
    global var2
    for i in range(10): 
        var1 += 1
        var2 += 1

def create2(): 
    tasks = [create.remote(i) for i in range(20)]
    ray.get(tasks)

create2()
```

This errors because Ray does not allow global variables to be used in the traditional way. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to create a method **`.add1()`** for either of quasi-`global`-s, the implementation of which will deliver a request to add 1 to the `main`.

This way the `main` is able to maintain a cheapest ( not overly expensive ) atomicity of incrementing any quasi-`global`, due to an enforced **`[SERIAL]`**-signal processing of otherwise principally `[CONCURRENT]`-signal arrival(s).

Possible vehicles for doing that are ZeroMQ `PUSH/PULL` and `nanomsg` or pynng `push/pull` Scalable Formal Communication Pattern archetypes.

Each `@ray.remote`-decorated execution may setup its own `{ PUSH | push }`-side of the signalling path, whereas the `main`-side or its { thread | process }-based spin-off just populates a central `{ PULL | pull }`-side, located at a constant `.bind( <Transport_Class>:<Port#orOtherAdressSpecifier> )` "collection-service" location. Each of the `PUSH`-ers `.connect()` to that a priori known *TransportClass* target-address and the rest is trivial.

Using more robust, error-resilient methods is also possible, depends on your needs. So no `global`-s needed for doing this or more complex `any:M+N`-resilient voting-, collector- or generic multi-agent distributed signalling.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an actor that holds the variables and update it.

```py
@ray.remote
class GlobalState:
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = {
            "var1": 0,
            "var2": 0
        }
    def increment(key):
        self.state[key] += 1

@ray.remote
def create(global_state): 
    for i in range(10): 
        global_state.increment.remote("var1")
        global_state.increment.remote("var2")

def create2(global_state): 
    tasks = [create.remote(global_state) for i in range(20)]
    ray.get(tasks)

global_state = GlobalState.remote()
create2(global_state)
```